# SYNTAX HELP: How to Find control in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side, ascx

I am trying to implement server side code on client side. "trvddl1" is a ascx control which contains a dropdownlist "ddltree". It was easy on server side but I am facing difficulty using the same in javascript.

How do I write the following code in javascript?

```
((DropDownList)trvddl1.FindControl("ddltree")).SelectedValue;
```

I tried

```
var abc = document.getElementById('<%=trvddl1.ClientID%>').value;
```

and

```
var Region = document.getElementById('<%=trvddl1.FindControl("ddltree")%>').value;
```

but javascript returned error. Is there some other keyword I am missing ?

Comment: When you view-source, what does your Javascript end up looking like?  What does your DOM end up looking like?

Comment: it came out like this .. 
 <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$trvddl1$ddltree" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$trvddl1$ddltree\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_trvddl1_ddltree" class="dropdownstyle">

Comment: Now look for your Javascript and see if the `var Region =` line ends up with `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_trvddl1_ddltree` (the id attribute) in the parameter.  If not, your ASP is giving you the wrong ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the HTML output (Browser-->View Source) and locate the control there, see what the ID of that control has, and put that one into the getElementById() function.

Example:

```
<input id='ddltree' .... />
```

Then use:

```
var abc = document.getElementById('ddltree').value;
```

Comment: the id came out as  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_trvddl1_ddltree" should I be writing document.getElementById('trvddl1_ddltree').value; ?

Comment: yes, because External JS files cannot access elements using `<%=trvddl1.ClientID%>` you need to know the actual id, and don't worry, that id won't change unless you make critical changes to some parent containers (like your ContentPlaceHolder id)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try something like that:

```
// find all controls that have an id that ends with ddltree 
// starts with would be [id*=ddltree]
var abc = document.querySelectorAll("[id$=ddltree]");
if(abc.length > 0) { 
   // got it !
   console.log(abc[0].value);
}
```

Please note that `querySelectorAll` is not supported in all browsers (even though - most). Here is a [reference](http://caniuse.com/queryselector).